# cambiar el valor de una tabla cuando se actualiza en mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo una tabla llamada cuentas con una columna llamada token, mediante php el token se calcula aleatoria mente y cuando alguien se "logea" ese token le cambia a ese usuario.

Ahora lo que intento hacer es que una vez cambie el token (la tabla sufra un update) el token que se ha cambiado, se espere X minutos y luego ponga un número aleatorio en ese token (para que no sea el mismo).

la función para el tiempo la he buscado y creo que es

WAITFOR DELAY '00:01';

La del número aleatorio esta misma:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(9999999999999999999-10+1))+10;
```

Y en dbeaver he intentado poner la siguiente función:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_cambiartoken$$ CREATE TRIGGER trigger_cambiartoken
BEFORE UPDATE ON cuentas FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.token THEN
WAITFOR DELAY '00:01';  
set NEW.token = "abc";
END IF;
END
```

Entendiendo que cuando la tabla cuentas sufre un update busca en cada fila, si la columna y la fila token cambia espera 1 minuto y pone en el nuevo token "abc" (para luego cambiarlo por el número aleatorio.

cuando ejecuto el script en dbeaver (seleccionandolo y dandole a control+intro) me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: resultado de la ejecución del script]

El tema es que no me funciona, cambio el valor de una fila de cuentas, el valor de token, y no me lo "cambia automaticamente".

---

Gracias por las respuestas, al final para evitar problemas lo que hice fue que cuando te logueas crea un token encriptado con el nombre de usuario y la fechayhora actual, y cada vez que se ejecuta una funcion, comprueba ese toquen, desencriptandolo, comprobando que el nombre está en la bd y comparando esa fecha conla que hay ahora actual, y si supera X minutos return false y entonces da el error de token caducado y la funcion no continua... así no tengo que ir cambiando y mirando la bd por el token

Answer (score 0):

Yo me olvidaría del disparador y utilizaría directamente:

```
UPDATE cuentas set token=(
    SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(9999999999999999999-10+1))+10
  ) WHERE id_cuenta=1;
DO SLEEP(5);
UPDATE cuentas set token=(
    SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(9999999999999999999-10+1))+10
  ) WHERE id_cuenta=1;
```

El problema del `TRIGGER BEFORE` es que te bloqueará el `UPDATE` hasta que pase ese tiempo y da la sensación de que necesitas el token activo en la base de datos desde el login hasta que su valor cambie.

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_update_cuentas
  BEFORE UPDATE ON cuentas FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DO SLEEP(5);
    SET new.token=(
      SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(9999999999999999999-10+1))+10
    );
  END;
```

Y, en el caso del `TRIGGER AFTER`, entrarías en un bucle sin fin:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_update_cuentas
  AFTER UPDATE ON cuentas FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DO SLEEP(5);
    UPDATE cuentas set token=(
        SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(9999999999999999999-10+1))+10
      ) WHERE id_cuenta=old.id_cuenta;
  END;
```

¿Y por qué no guardas la hora de inicio de sesión y simplemente la cierras cuando haya transcurrido el tiempo que te interese?

Comment: necesito que tras iniciar sesión, a las X horas, el token cambie para que se tenga que loguear de nuevo (seguridad para que si se te olvida la sesión abierta no la use otro), el tema que pones de utilizar directamente el update es que solo necesito que el token cambie tras pasados X tiempo del logueo...
1ºte logueas, y en tu usuario se te pone un token (ese toquen se requiere en todas las funciones que busca en la base de datos mediante php) 
2ºtras X tiempo del logueo el token cambia (así al utilizar alguna de las funciones verá que el token es distinto y no te dejará interaccionar en la bd

Comment: Suponía que sería para algo así, pero eso es algo que puedes controlar con las propias variables de sesión o guardando en la base de datos la hora de inicio de la sesión

Comment: @ebsigma Tal vez esta pregunta te aporte alguna idea para lo que pretendes hacer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/553510