# Limitar Inicio de sesión en varios dispositivos con base de datos Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, login, session

Tengo un sistema de inicio de sesión web, donde si el usuario ya inició sesión en otro navegador o dispositivo bien sea desde el navegador de una pc o de un celular con iguales o diferentes IP, bloquee el nuevo inicio de sesión.

He conseguido setear una variable automática en la tabla del usuario llamada "cuentaactiva" en la base de datos cuando el usuario loguea y verificar dicha variable al iniciar sesión si coincide con la registrada, en caso de que coincida bloquea el ingreso hasta que no cierre la sesion en el otro dispositivo pero al momento de cerrar sesión no encuentro como sacar esa variable de la base de datos.

Acà les comparto mi código:

***Login***

```
<?php
session_start(); // Iniciando sesion
$error=''; 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos, intenta vericando tu fecha de pago.";
}
else
{

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

include("config/db.php");
include("config/conexion.php");

$cuentaactiva = "si";


$username    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($username,ENT_QUOTES)));
$password    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($password,ENT_QUOTES)));
// $password =  sha1($password);

// VALIDAR SESSION
$verificar_session = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE cuentaactiva='$cuentaactiva'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($verificar_session) > 0){ 
    echo'
    <script> 
    alert("Ya has iniciado sesion en otro dispositivo, cierra la sesiòn e intenta nuevamente.");
    window.location = "./index.php";
    </script>';
   exit();
}
// FIN VALIDAR

$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM login WHERE username = '" . $username . "' and password='".$password."';";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$counter=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($counter==1){
        $_SESSION['login_user_sys']=$username; 
        header("location: browse.php"); 
    
        $ses_sql="UPDATE login Set 
        cuentaactiva='$cuentaactiva'

        WHERE username='$username'"; 

        mysqli_query($con,$ses_sql); 

} else {
$error = "Usuario o contraseña incorrecto.";    
}
}
}
?>
```

***LOGOUT***

```
<?php

session_start();

include("config/db.php");
include("config/conexion.php");

$cuentaactiva = "no";
$_SESSION = $username;

//ACTUALIZAR 
$ses_sql="UPDATE login Set 
cuentaactiva='$cuentaactiva'

WHERE username='$username'"; 

mysqli_query($con,$ses_sql); 
//

mysqli_close($con); 

if(session_destroy()) 
{
header("Location: index.php"); 
}
?>
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: no deberias antes de destruir la session corroborrar que se cambio el dato a "no" dentro de la base de datos?

Comment: Te sugiero que crees una tabla donde esta almacene la informacion del dispositivo(id, modelo) y el id de la persona, con estos 3 campos tu podrás obtener una lista de los dispositivos que estén asociados al id del usuario y poder validar la longitud por ejemplo, si es mayor o igual a 3 que le salga una ventana emergente.

Comment: Gracias por las sugerencias amigos, tomare esto en cuenta también para validar

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con este ejemplo mínimo viable:

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','_so');
$txt=null;
if(isset($_GET['cerrar']) and isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){
    $conn->query("
        UPDATE usuarios SET f_fin=NOW()
          WHERE id_usuario=".intval($_SESSION['id_usuario']).";
    ");
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['id_usuario']) and isset($_POST['user'])){
    $rs=$conn->prepare("
        SELECT id_usuario,usuario,pass
          FROM usuarios
          WHERE usuario=?
          AND pass=md5(?)
          AND f_fin IS NOT NULL;
    ");
    $rs->bind_param('ss',$_POST['user'],$_POST['pass']);
    $rs->execute();
    $rs->bind_result($id,$u,$p);
    if($rs->fetch()){
        if($u==$_POST['user'] and $p==md5($_POST['pass'])){
            $rs->close();
            $_SESSION['id_usuario']=$id;
            $conn->query("
                UPDATE usuarios
                  SET f_ini=NOW(),f_fin=NULL
                  WHERE id_usuario=".intval($id).";
            ");
        }
    }
    else $txt.='<div style="background-color:pink">'
        .'No es posible acceder actualmente</div>';
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){
    $txt.='<form method="post" action="index.php">'
        .'<input name="user"/>'
        .'<input name="pass" type="password"/>'
        .'<button>Acceder</button>'
        .'</form>';
    echo $txt;
    exit();
}
$txt.='<div>Has conseguido acceder. <a href="?cerrar=1">Cerrar [x]</a></div>';
echo $txt;
```

Que hace uso de este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
  id_usuario int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  usuario varchar(31),
  pass varchar(32),
  f_ini datetime,
  f_fin datetime
  );
INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, pass, f_fin) VALUES
  ('kenmed',MD5('kenMed'),NOW());
```

Sería recomendable sustituir la línea:

```
AND f_fin IS NOT NULL;
```

Por:

```
AND (f_fin IS NOT NULL OR f_ini<NOW()-INTERVAL 6 HOUR);
```

De esta forma si, por cualquier motivo, el usuario no cierra la sesión, la cuenta no quedaría bloqueada por más de 6 horas, por ejemplo.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por el aporte amigo, intentare para validar, tengo pocos conocimientos en este campo de login y sesiones por lo que analizo en el código es que me toca crear una nueva base de datos

Comment: me encanta como se ve el codigo de los post con mi extension: https://i.imgur.com/3Xv9Ibk.png

Comment: [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias amigos, he conseguido lograr bloquear y desbloquear los inicios de sesiones para un solo dispositivo, en mi código logout solo basto verificar que la consulta de cambio de variable se realizara antes de destruir la sesión y al loguearse la variable se setea y se verifica al usuario que intenta acceder, habian varios errores pero logre soluicionar, aun sigo trabajando para que esta variable desaparezca en un tiempo determinado como menciono nuestro amigo @ArcanisGK507 así no queda la cuenta bloqueada de por vida, su código esta bueno pero no lo entendí del todo, gracias bro